# How can I get rid of multiple “purchased on <my iPhone>” playlists?

Tags: iphone, itunes

When I got my first iPhone and bought something via the iTunes app, I got a playlist in the iTunes source list underneath the “Store” heading for all the songs I purchased on the iPhone.

I’ve had a few more iPhones since then, and each phone has also been given its own “Purchased on” playlist in iTunes. They’re now taking up quite a lot of space in the iTunes menu.

Is there any way I can consolidate, or just get rid of, these playlists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't consolidate them, but you can delete them. Just right click and click "Delete".

Comment: Good lord, indeed you can. Excellent, cheers Kyle!

Comment: It is possible to consolidate them.

Answer (score 2):

To consolidate them into one play list, you need to go into the other otherplay lists, slect all the tracks, then you can right click and select "Add to playlist" and select one of the other "Purchased on iPhone..." playlists, repeat for all the extra playlists, then when they are consolidated delete the spare ones.

A similar process is detailed in [this Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25119).